# Error message refers to file with contents that don't exist there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a web app and I'm getting this error in the browser console:

```
dinnerOverviewView:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I'm surprised that there should be a `<` in my javascript code, so I look into the file `js/view/dinnerOverviewView.js`. There is no `<` there. So I click on the error in the browser, and I'm shown this:

[image]

This is not the file `js/view/dinnerOverviewView.js` on my system. That file looks like this:

```
var DinnerOverviewView = function(container, model){
    var container = container;
    var model = model;
}
```

In fact, the browser is showing me the index.html file, and is somehow interpreting it as javascript and claiming that it resides at `js/view/dinnerOverviewView` without the `.js` extension. A lot of craziness! What is going on here? I've reloaded but it doesn't fix the issue.

Extra info:

I'm hosting the server locally using `npm start`.

Other parts of the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <body>

    <!--- empty placeholders for external HTML-->
    <div id="welcome"></div>
    <div id="dinnerOverview"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>

    <!-- The application JavaScript code -->
    <script src="js/model/dinnerModel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/view/sidebarView.js"></script>
    <script src="js/view/dishReelView.js"></script>
    <script src="js/view/welcomeView.js"></script>
    <script src="js/view/dinnerOverviewView"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/sidebarController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/generalController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/view/dinnerOverviewView.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

js/app.js:

```
$(function() {
    //We instantiate our model
    var model = new DinnerModel();

    // We instantiate the general controller
    var generalController = new GeneralController();
    // And create the instance of ExampleView
    var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
    var sidebarView = new SideBarView(sidebar, model); 
    generalController.addView(sidebarView);
    var sidebarController = new SideController(sidebar, model);

    var dinnerOverview = $("dinnerOverview");
    var dinnerOverviewView = new DinnerOverviewView(dinnerOverview, model);
    generalController.addView(dinnerOverviewView);
    var dinnerOverviewController = new dinnerOverviewController(dinnerOverview, model);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.js` at the end of `<script src="js/view/dinnerOverviewView"></script>`.

Should be:
`<script src="js/view/dinnerOverviewView.js"></script>`